# PHP regular expressions (phonenumber)

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'm having some trouble with a regular expression for phone numbers. I am trying to create a regex that is as broad as possible for european phone numbers. The phone number can start with a + or with two leading 0's, followed by a number in between 0 and 40. this is not necessary however, so this first part can also ignored. After that, it should all be numbers, grouped into pairs of at least two, with a whitespace or a - inbetween the groups.

The regex I have put together can be found below.

```
/((\+|00)+[0-4]+[0-9]+)?([ -]?[0-9]{2,15}){1,5}/
```

This should match the following structures

```
0031 34-56-78
0032123456789
0033 123 456 789
0034-123-456-789

+35 34-56-78
+36123456789
+37 123 456 789
+38-123-456-789
...
```

What it also matches according to my javascript

```
+32 a54b 67-0:
```

So I must have made a mistake somewhere, but I really can't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a small note: You use `+` in places where you mean "one occurrence". `+` however means "at least one". So you might want to consider erasing all `+` in the first part of the regex, as every single group in there should occur exactly once and the following `?` will then make the whole thing optional.

Comment: Use `\s` instead of putting whitespace directly

Comment: It's the `[0-9]{2,15}` that matches, the first regex part being optional. As the answers say, you wanted to constraint the match to the whole string (start end assertions).

Comment: TillHelgeHelwig: Thanks for the advice, I deleted all the + in there :)
Shameer: why should you use \s and not a direct whitespace? :)

Comment: EU numbers start with 3 or 4 (except for Faroe Islands(298) and Greenland(299)) and some countries got 3 numbers in there prefix for country code so i expanded on the regex a bit and made it so it only had 2 capture groups (prefix and number)
`^((?:00|\+)(?:[34][0-9]{1,2}|298|299))?[ -]?((?:[0-9]{2,15}[ -]?){1,5})$`

Comment: Thanks Blem, this is a nice addition again :) only one question, what's the ?: for?

Comment: () in regex creates a capture group, once you have run your regex you can pull out the information that was inside, by adding ?: at start it it dose not create a capture group, in the regex i posted it only have 2 () with out :? one around the prefix and one around the number, so once you have run the regex you can pull out the prefix and number to seperat values if you want

Comment: here is an example:
`if (ereg ("^((?:00|\+)(?:[34][0-9]{1,2}|298|299))?[ -]?((?:[0-9]{2,15}[ -]?){1,5})$", $var, $regs)) {
    $countrycode = $regs[1];
    $number = $regs[2];
}` (sorry it dos not look good in comments)

Comment: No problem, I understand now how it works :) It's a very handy thing to know :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use anchors `^ $` to define the start and ending of the string and will therefore find a match anywhere in the string.

```
/^((\+|00)+[0-4]+[0-9]+)?([ -]?[0-9]{2,15}){1,5}$/
```

Adding anchors will do the trick. More about these meta characters can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick and link also helped me understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

Put `^` in the beginning of the RegExp and `$` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be can help you.

```
if (ereg("^((\([0-9]{3}\) ?)|([0-9]{3}-))?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$",$var)) 
{
    $valid = true; 
}
```